# SharePoint 2013 search moving a large site from one content source to new content source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

We are maintaining SharePoint 2013 on premises environment with Search index 15 M items.

We have one large content source with two site collections( Site1, Site2) each having 150 GB data.

We moved site2 to new content database and now planning to move the site 2 to new content source .

Can we edit the existing content source with removing site2 url and then create new content source with adding site2 url? Is this approach fine?

Will the existing index for site2 removed and create the new index post this change?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can move the site to a new content database without changing
   your Content Source.
2. If the site collection is hosted by a separate web application you
   can move it to a new Content Source with a unique start address.
3. Changing the first content source and performing a recrawl will issue deletes against the index for the removed content source. You should plan for this and choose your indexing schedule accordingly.
4. None of these activities will "create a new index". There is only one index per SSA and with 15M items in 2013 you should be running 2 index partitions (10M items per partition) in 2016/2019 you can run 20M items per partition.

Comment: I moved the site to new content database but post that, the new documents added to the site are not being crawled and receiving the below error message ' Directory links across partitions are not allowed' .   Tried incremental crawl and reindexed the document libraries hosting new documents but still issue is not resolved.  Hence planning to move the site to new content source and do full craw.

Comment: After the move did you perform a full crawl?

Comment: No i did not perform full crawl for this site which i moved to new Database. Is it must to perform full crawl?

Comment: I would, the full crawl will clean up the index and should correct and delete the old index entries.

Comment: thanks for update. But I  noticed that site old index was automatically deleted with the message 'Deleted by the gatherer (This item was deleted because its parent was deleted) . This old index clean up was done after 15 days of moving the site to new content database.  How this index cleanup was done ?

Comment: No idea. I think you need to be sure of your terminology. There is only one index per SSA.